# use of for xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a code like this for concatenating values from multiple rows

input:

```
ID             Name
-------------  ----------------------
1              Deepak Kumar Goyal
2              Niladri Biswas
2              Priyanka Sarkar
3              Sumi Girijan
3              Suresh Beldar
3              Jeeva Baby
```

expected output:

```
ID      Name
------- --------------------------------------------------
1       Deepak Kumar Goyal
2       Niladri Biswas OR Priyanka Sarkar
3       Sumi Girijan AND Suresh Beldar AND Jeeva Baby
```

query used:

```
select ID, SUBSTRING(
(
select  ','+CAST(name AS VARCHAR)
from  @t a where a.ID = b.ID
FOR XML PATH('') 
),2,2000) as names
 from @t b group by id
```

Query runs successfully. Can you help me understand the need of xml here and how and why its working?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a common (mis?)use of the `FOR XML` clause of SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't have the `group_concat` function that some other SQL implementations have (such as MySQL) that allows a query to aggregate multiple fields into a single field.

The `FOR XML` clause tells the server to combine the resulting rows into an XML document, and it does this by concatenating the values of the specified field. In the above query, you are exploiting the string concatenation used to generate XML and adding your (decidedly not XML) comma separator during this process.

In short: It's a hack, but it works well and it's used widely.

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx